# Is it safe to install kernel 4.1.3 lts (latest version) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

As we already know Kernel version 4.1.3 LTS is announced but Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is still using kernel 3.13.

What could be benefits to install latest kernel version on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Also, I don't have any plan to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to higher version. As of now I want to stay with 14.04 LTS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

I've recently upgraded my kernel to 4.1.3 and there are many features that are not supported. Like for instance , when I close the lid of my laptop I expect it to Hibernate but it doesn't do so. And there are also many GRUB related issues which I had to fix. Finally I got rid of it and rolled back to  3.16.0-45-generic. Although , you might want to experiment you can install the latest kernel and when you want the older kernel to boot you can do it so  from the GRUB boot menu by pressing LShift.